# Can a Raspberry Pi be used for high-voltage parallel programming?

Tags: raspberry-pi, programmer

I have a Raspberry Pi 2, and [I know it's possible to use an Raspberry PI for programming an AVR](https://learn.adafruit.com/program-an-avr-or-arduino-using-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins/overview), but I came across something.

Apparently if you brick your chip by fiddling with the fuses you need a programmer with "high-voltage parallel programming" capabilities, as stated [here](http://hackaday.com/2010/10/25/avr-programming-02-the-hardware/).

The fuses I mention here are not to be mistaken for fuses like the ones you find in your house; the fuses I'm talking about are the ones set by software running on the AVR chip. The link above also states that HVPP can be done with an Arduino.

Does the Raspberry Pi have high-voltage parallel programming capabilities?

Comment: The answer is "yes, it is possible". Beware of asking yes/no questions here, especially when the implied "how?" is too broad for the format we use here.

Comment: For AVR *high voltage* programming you need (relatively) *high voltage* of 12V. As long as the Pi cannot provide or handle 12V by itself it cannot perform "high voltage programming" by itself.

Answer (score 7):

No.

It says that you can use an Arduino for HVPP *with additional hardware*. Similar hardware (a shield or hat or pants or whatever Raspberry Pi calls it) could be developed for the Raspberry Pi, but you can't do it "out of the box".

Comment: How would one go about making a shield for the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: That's a different question.

Answer (score 2):

The Pi has no high voltage capability, but it can drive a transistor which controls the high voltage.
Shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm not certain how to do it myself.
It is something that I want to do myself, and it may yet get to the top of my todo list.